# Why does DbMetal Generate Table Attribute with "main"?

Tags: sqlite, dblink, dbmetal

I'm a newbie with DBLink and Sqlite. When DbMetal generates Nortwind.cs (C#) it marks some methods with a Table attribute:

```
[Table(Name="main.Categories")]    // C#
```

After I used DbMetal to create a Nortwind.vb (VB.Net) file, the test program aborted because there was no table named "main.Categories". However, when I removed "main.", it works:

```
' VB.Net

<Table(Name:="Categories")> _
```

I'm just not understand why "main" is generated at all. Why does it work for C# but not for VB.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbMetal generates "main" by default. It can be changed by specifying the --database argument when in the "generate .dbml file" mode. However, as of this time, the class name can be changed using --database but it still writes "main" in the Table attribute so back to square one until it's fixed.

http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/DbMetal