# How to set the DataContext class name with DbMetal?

Tags: .net, dblinq, dbmetal

DbLinq's DbMetal generates a `Main` class which inherits `DataContext`. I don't want it to be `Main`. How to change that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409241/why-does-dbmetal-generate-table-attribute-with-main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DbMetal will always generate a class called `Main` by default. However, you can use the --database option when generating the .dbml.

Oops: found this here in SO: [Why does DbMetal Generate Table Attribute with "main"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409241/why-does-dbmetal-generate-table-attribute-with-main)

Comment: It worked! I thought this argument would search for another database inside the file, but it uses the same database and only renames the generated class.