# Change class name in pre-build event

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dbmetal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the DataContext class name with DbMetal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878493/how-to-set-the-datacontext-class-name-with-dbmetal)

I use DbMetal in my pre-build event to generate the desired code file. DbMetal generates a class called `Main`. In its wiki I can'f find a parameter to change that default value.

In the pre-build event (after generating that code file above) I would like to automatically refactor and change the class name.

**Is there any native way to do so within the pre-build events?**

If not I would be forced to write my own little parser that does the job and call it there.

---

(I actually don't know wheter pre-/post-build events are supported in VS2005/2008. Feel free to add the tags of this question.)

Comment: It is right on the first google hit, Brian's comment on June 19th.  http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/DbMetal

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409241/why-does-dbmetal-generate-table-attribute-with-main, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878493/how-to-set-the-datacontext-class-name-with-dbmetal

Comment: Hans Passant: You might want to post this as an answer ;) My bad, Seems like I have totally missed those comments.